# Timber use different template for custom post type

Tags: wordpress, twig, timber

I am completely new to PHP, Wordpress and Timber. I have a custom post type called **Projects**, it uses the posts archive template and I am going crazy to create a specific **Projects archive template** so I can have a different layout for it.

This is what my index.twig looks like

```
{% extends "layouts/base.twig" %}

{% block content %}
  <div class="uk-child-width-1-3@m" uk-grid uk-scrollspy="cls: uk-animation-fade; target: > div > .uk-card; delay: 500; repeat: false">
{% for post in posts %}
    {% include "tease-post.twig" %}
{% endfor %}
  </div>
{% endblock %}
```

and this is the tease-post.twig

```
{% block content %}
<div>
    <div class="uk-card uk-card-default">
            <div class="uk-card-media-top">
                    <a href="{{post.link}}"><img src="{{post.thumbnail.src('full')}}" alt=""></a>
            </div>
            <div class="uk-card-body">
                    <h3 class="uk-card-title"><a href="{{post.link}}" class="uk-button uk-button-text">{{post.title}}</a></h3>
                    <p>{{post.get_preview(25,false,false,true)}}</p>
            </div>
            <div class="uk-card-footer">
                    <a href="{{post.link}}" class="uk-button uk-button-text">Read more</a>
            </div>
    </div>
</div>
{% endblock %}
```

Any idea how it works? Can't find any related documentation..

Comment: Check out https://wphierarchy.com/ to find the right name for your custom post type archive template.

Answer (score 1):

There are a few diff't methods depending on what you're looking to achieve. It would seem the simplest is...

```
{% extends "layouts/base.twig" %}

{% block content %}
    <div class="uk-child-width-1-3@m" uk-grid uk-scrollspy="cls: uk-animation-fade; target: > div > .uk-card; delay: 500; repeat: false">
    {% for post in posts %}
        {% include "tease-'~ post.type ~'.twig" %}
    {% endfor %}
    </div>
{% endblock %}
```

You could then create a file called `tease-project.twig` (assuming that `project is the name of your custom post type's slug) that might look something like this...

```
{# tease-project.twig #}
<h2>My cool project is... {{ post.title }}</h2>
```

#### If you're looking to do something special with a CPT's specific archive page...

Check your `archive.php` file, if you're using the [starter theme](https://github.com/timber/starter-theme/blob/master/archive.php) it should load a file called `archive-projects.twig` (assuming that `projects` is the name of the custom post type).

The logic is fully customizable so you can load any `.twig` files you want depending on the circumstance